# In iOS make a UIButton have a same effect like keyboard key

Tags: ios, keyboard, uibutton

I am working on a interface with a lot of buttons. I would like to have two effects from the keyboard key.

1. In the iPhone keyboard, after you press a key like "G" ,before your finger leave the screen, you can always move your finger to another key ,and the input will be the one when your finger leave the screen.
2. When you press a key in the iPhone keyboard, the key will somehow be a larger one.

Because I also have a lot of buttons and they are also small ones like the keyboard. So I think this to effects will help the user to press the button more easily without errors. Can a normal UIButton do this?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The effects you described are both already in the normal keyboard.

Comment: I know the normal keyboard can do this. So I'm asking how a normal button can have the same effect like the key(button) in the normal keyboard.Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass) for that effect. For the other effect you should read about [Touch Events](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-learning-about-touch-events-basic-game-animation/)

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (location.x >= img.x && location.x <= img.x && location.y >= img.y && location.y <= img.y)
    {
        // your code here...
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The normal UIButton can be made to do this, but you'll have to write the grow/shrink code yourself. The basic idea would be to use the Touch Down event to fire the code that grows the currently-touched button (and shrink any previously touched buttons). Then use the Touch Up Inside event to determine when the user took her finger off the button. The button that receives the Touch Up Inside will be the last button the user touched.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that the button "holds" the touch event. I'm afraid that my suggestion is completely bogus and I'm going to upvote @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on the concept he's describing.